# Dropzone check if files names exists before processing queue

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am using dropzone for uploading files which I save with some meta data in a database in the backend.
When a user tries to upload a bulk of files I want to check if he has already uploaded a file with this name and warn him with an alert with an option to continue ot stop.

So I disabled the `autoProcessQueue`.
I am also listening for `addedfile` event, I get the name, I perform an ajax to check if it exists in the database and return true or false, good.

Let's say the user tries to upload 40 files which all already exist, I don't want 40 warnings that this file already exists, I want one notification printing all 40 filenames.
I was looking for `addedfile` but for multiple files, I didn't found a solution.

Here is my code for now
This is where I'm stuck
How can I know when I've checked every file ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        @if(isset($checkRoute))
            function filenameExists(name) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '{{ $checkRoute }}',
                    data: {
                        name: name
                    }
                })
                .done(function(res) {
                    // returns true or false
                    return res
                })
                .fail(function(err) {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            }
        @endif

        let existingFilenames = []

        let fileCount = 0

        $('#{{ $element_id }}').dropzone({
            url: "{{ $upload }}", // Set the url for your upload script location
            paramName: "documents", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
            maxFiles: 100,
            maxFilesize: 100, // MB
            parallelUploads: 100,
            timeout: 240000,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            acceptedFiles: "application/msword, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/pdf, image/*, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, image/*",
            uploadMultiple: true,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
            },
            init: function() {
                @if(isset($checkRoute))
                    this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
                        console.log(this.getAcceptedFiles())
                        fileCount++
                        if (filenameExists(file.name)) {
                            console.log(file.name)
                            existingFilenames.push(file.name)
                        }
                    })
                @endif
            },
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            sendingmultiple: function (files) {
                // Begin loading
                KTApp.blockPage({
                    overlayColor: '#000000',
                    type: 'v2',
                    state: 'success',
                    message: '{{ __('documents_uploading') }}'
                });
            },
            queuecomplete: function () {
                // End loading
                KTApp.unblockPage();

                $.notify({
                    // options
                    message: '{{ __('documents_upload_success') }}'
                }, {
                    // settings
                    type: 'success',
                    placement: {
                        from: "top",
                        align: "center"
                    },
                    animate: {
                        enter: 'animated fadeInDown',
                        exit: 'animated fadeOutUp'
                    },
                });

                window.location.replace("{{ $redirect }}");
            }
        });
    });
```

Another thing that concerns me is how will I process the queue at the press of the button in the notification.

Comment: Well, if you push all the warnings in one array and print it all together?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem as i wanted to provide the user with a dropdown of different upload directories on the server.

As each directory has a different ruleset of `acceptedFiles`, the static option `acceptedFiles` was out of the question.

Instead i used a combination of listening to the `drop` event on dropzone `init` and to "extend" the `accept` function:

The `drop` event gets the total number of files dropped and stores it in `droppedFilesCounter`. It also initializes/resets a global Object `dzCustomFeedback` and clears the "feedback" area from prior feedback.

The extended `accept` function, which is called for by each dropped file checks which upload directory is currently selected and compares the current file extension against the configured accepted ones.

If there is a match the `done()` function "bubbles" an "all clear".

Otherwise the file is removed from the preview list (or actually never makes it into it) and the global `dzCustomFeedback` Object cumulates error-messages of the type `invalidFileTypes` for all files accordingly.

Once all files have been run through the `accept` function (`droppedFilesCounter` == 0) and some feedback messages have been prepared the `prepareFeedback` function is called, which basically populates a jQuery `<div>` container with the cumulated content of `dzCustomFeedback`.

```
init: function() {
  var myDropzone = this;

  myDropzone.on("drop", function(event) {

    if(typeof event.dataTransfer.files == 'object')
    {
      droppedFilesCounter = event.dataTransfer.files.length;
    }

    dzCustomFeedback = {};
    jQuery('#dz-feedback').empty();
  });
},
accept: function(file, done) {
    / * Erweiterung der vordefinierten accept Function * /
    customTypeSelector = document.getElementById("selectUploadFolder");
    var currentAcceptedFiles = customTypeAcceptedFiles[customTypeSelector.options[customTypeSelector.selectedIndex].value]
    var currentFileExtension = file.name.split(".").pop()

    droppedFilesCounter--;

    if (typeof customTypeAcceptedFiles[customTypeSelector.options[customTypeSelector.selectedIndex].value] == "object"
        &&
        jQuery.inArray(currentFileExtension, currentAcceptedFiles["extensions"] ) >= 0) {
        //accepted file
        done();
    }
    else {
        //Unaccepted file revert
        this.removeFile(file);
        if(typeof dzCustomFeedback["invalidFileTypes"] == "undefined")
        {
          dzCustomFeedback["invalidFileTypes"] = {
                                      "msg": [
                                                uploadDndConf["textElements"]["invalidFileTypesUploadFolder"].replace("{{uploadFolder}}", currentAcceptedFiles["label"])
                                              , currentAcceptedFiles["extensions"].join()
                                             ]
                                    , "type": "error"
                                    , "filesIgnored": {} };
        }
        dzCustomFeedback["invalidFileTypes"]["filesIgnored"][file.name] = file;
        done(this.options.dictInvalidFileType);
    }
    if(droppedFilesCounter == 0 && !jQuery.isEmptyObject(dzCustomFeedback))
    {
      prepareFeedback(dzCustomFeedback);
    }
},
```